# Having collaboration with other professors

Tags: professorship, collaboration

I graduated with math degree. Now I want to conduct research which is a kind of combination of two subjects X and Y. I found another professor (by googling) in different country who is working on Y. My question is that: How can I ask the professor to have a joint work? May you please give me a proper text for my request?

Comment: You should write this yourself, we don’t even know what Y is... This is not a difficult letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Professors are people, too. They are not robots to be sent a formal instruction code. Write an email like you are talking to a human. Introduce yourself, introduce your background, clearly explain your proposal. Don't forget to clearly say what is X and Y and why you think working on their combination is a good idea.

Professors are often very busy but they also value good collaborations and will respond if your idea is clearly explained and is promising.